# Prelude.read: no parse && Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Text’ In the first argument of ‘WeatherValues’, namely ‘tempMin’

Tags: haskell, aeson

How can I fix it? `Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual 
type ‘Text’`
I can not use text in place of a double.And this is a response

**Response**

```
{responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 200, statusMessage = "OK"}, 
responseVersion = HTTP/1.1, responseHeaders = [("Server","openresty"),
("Date","Wed, 16 May 2018 11:12:26 GMT"),("Content-Type","application/json; 
charset=utf-8"),("Content-Length","446"),("Connection","keep-alive"),("X-Cache-
Key","/data/2.5/weather?q=yerevan,am"),("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"),
("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true"),("Access-Control-Allow-
Methods","GET, POST")], responseBody = "{\"coord\":
{\"lon\":44.51,\"lat\":40.18},\"weather\":
[{\"id\":801,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"few 
clouds\",\"icon\":\"02d\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":
{\"temp\":298.15,\"pressure\":1019,\"humidity\":23,\"temp_min\":298.15,\"temp_ma
x\":298.15},\"visibility\":10000,\"wind\":
{\"speed\":1.5,\"deg\":220},\"clouds\":{\"all\":20},\"dt\":1526466600,\"sys\":
{\"type\":1,\"id\":7226,\"message\":0.0032,\"country\":\"AM\",\"sunrise\":152643
5114,\"sunset\":1526487120},\"id\":616052,\"name\":\"Yerevan\",\"cod\":200}", 
responseCookieJar = CJ {expose = []}, responseClose' = ResponseClose}
```

**Code:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}    

module PrepareAnswer where

import           Control.Monad
import           Data.Maybe
import           GHC.Generics

import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString          as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy     as BSL
import           Data.Text
import           Network.HTTP.Client
import           Text.Read
import           Data.Text         
import           Text.JSON
import           AskWeather

data WeatherValues = WeatherValues
               { temp_min :: Double          
            -- , temp_max :: Text
            -- , pressure :: Text
            -- , speed     :: Text
               } deriving (Show) -- Здесь speed подразумевается как скорость ветра

prepareAnswer :: Response BSL.ByteString -> Text
prepareAnswer response = Data.Text.pack . show $ weatherValues
    where
      --finalPhrase = createFinalPrase preparedValues
    --  preparedValues = prepareValues weatherValues
        weatherValues = extractValues . responseBody $ response

extractValues :: BSL.ByteString -> WeatherValues
extractValues rawJSON =
    let result  = decode' rawJSON
    in case result of
        Nothing   -> error "Invalid JSON!"
        Just info -> 
                let  tempMin   = getTempMin info
          --       tempMax   = getTempMax   info
           --      pressInfo = getPressure  info
           --  windSpeed = getWindSpeed info
        in WeatherValues tempMin -- tempMax pressInfo windSpeed

getTempMin :: Object -> Text
getTempMin info =
    case parseMaybe extractTempMin info of 
        Nothing -> "Invalid JSON!"
        Just info -> info 
    where
        extractTempMin = \info -> info .: "main"
                         >>=
                         \mainInfo -> mainInfo .: "temp_min"
```

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions here, and neither is really clear. Please focus on one problem and make a [MCVE] for it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I changed the question how to fix it
 Prelude.read: no parse

Comment: @AshotBes Edits should be used to clarify or improve a question only, not to change the question substantively (or else the question and any existing answers would drift out of synch). I have rolled back your edit for you. If you have new problems, you are welcome to open a fresh question, but you should take a little time to do some debugging yourself. My hint below should point you in the right direction. If you end up opening another question, do read about how to create an MCVE, do link to this question, and do make sure you explicitly say what is different in your new question.

Answer (score 2):

These three snippets from your code are irreconcilable:

```
data WeatherValues = WeatherValues
           { temp_min :: Double
           }

let tempMin = getTempMin info
in WeatherValues tempMin

getTempMin :: Object -> Text
```

Probably the right solution is to adjust `getTempMin` to return a `Maybe Double` (by parsing the `Text` you extract in some way, perhaps), and also to adjust `extractValues` to return a `Maybe WeatherValues`.

Comment: I tried writing this 
in WeatherValues  (read $ show tempMin :: Double) 
it was compiled but during the run I was getting an error NO PARSE

Comment: @AshotBes That's because your JSON object doesn't have text under the keys main/temp_min; it has a number...